# Story about lost colonized planet sent into orbit around "free" star

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the name of a book I read, here are some details:

- Main character is some sort of detective/investigator (I think)
- Sci-fi, takes place in distant future.  Oldest known relic is an american coin (from 2006 I think)
- Hired to track down whether or not a cup is authentic from a lost ship
- They end up finding the ship, but not the planet that it was sent to colonize.
- They are bringing back a bunch of relics from the ship when they decided to stay over in the space station for a bite to eat.  The shuttle carrying the relics is destroyed (they were supposed to be on it but weren't).
- They end up following the clues and finding the lost colonized planet which is orbiting a star which is on some sort of crazy orbit through the galaxy which is why no one was able to find it before.

Comment: I can't tell from the question, but do you mean "lost colonized **plant**"? Or **planet**? The latter seems more likely, but before I edited I thought...it would be an interesting story too if it were a plant...

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.  A lost colonized plant?  Thats been done before: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoville.

Comment: [Whoville with more believable characters.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_Trees) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story identification - Fabled spaceship wreck discovery leads to planet full of descendants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178601/story-identification-fabled-spaceship-wreck-discovery-leads-to-planet-full-of)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's [*Seeker*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seeker_%28novel%29) by Jack McDevitt, the third in his "Alex Benedict" series.