# Trying to find a space archeologist/explorer book I read once before, can't remember the name or author

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book series of which I read one book that was right smack in the middle of the series... but it seems as if each book can stand alone really. unfortunately I have totally forgotten the name and author, I hope someone can help. Ok here goes:
Book is set in the distant future. It centers around an archeologist/scavanger who finds ancient crash sites. He or She? I'll say he for now, finds an artifact. A cup I believe with ancient writing on it. This leads him on a chase to find out where its from and it ends up being from one of the first space colony ships to leave earth or something like that. This prompts him to try to find the ship which was lost long ago.... He ends finding a planet that is following a rouge star that ripped apart the solar system the people of the ship were supposed to get to. The planet is populated by the descendants of colony ship, and they are completely unaware where they originally came from. I also remember that they lived on a ring around the world because one side of the ring was to hot and the other to cold.

Also remember there being one Alien species that was telepathic and had very sharp teeth. It was mentioned that when we met them our tech was similar in advancement they were better at some things and we were better at others...

My brother read another book in the series and told me it has to do with the hero going to a vacation planet where there are vampire stories and it ends up being that planet's government doing the kidnappings or something like that.

Well I hope you guys can help I'm at a total loss and its killing me. was such a great read!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/story-about-lost-colonized-planet-sent-into-orbit-around-free-star

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like the [Alex Benedict](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1/183-2851643-1997307?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=alex+benedict+series) series by [Jack McDevitt.](http://www.jackmcdevitt.com/) The series is about the adventures of archaeologist Alex Benedict. It's set about 9600 years in the future, 200 years after a long war with the Ashiyyur, a telepathic alien race.

In [*Seeker:*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441013759)

> In 2688, interstellar transports Seeker and Bremerhaven left a
>   theocratic Orwellian Earth to found a dictator-free society,
>   Margolia—and vanished. Nine thousand years later, with a flawed
>   humanity spread over 100-odd worlds, Margolia and its ships have
>   become Atlantis-type myths, but after a cup from Seeker falls into the
>   hands of antiquarian Alex Benedict, the hero of McDevitt's Polaris
>   (2004), Alex determines to win everlasting fame and vaster fortune by
>   finding them

Comment: Your brother's book is "The Devil's Eye" also by Jack McDevitt.